# Calling an R function with a vector of variables names using do.call()

Tags: r

I have written a function in R called `by_group()`. The `by_group()` function expects its first argument to be a `data frame`, followed by an arbitrary number of character arguments that refer to existing variables inside the `data frame`.

I want to call `by_group()` (within another function), without knowing in advance how many variables the user will have passed. This works if I do it explicitly, referring to the input `data frame` and variables like so:

```
output <- by_group(df, "var1", "var2",...)
```

I can similarly get the function to work if I use the `do.call()` function:

```
output <- do.call(by_group, as.list(c(df, "var1", "var2"))
```

Now suppose I have a vector of the variable names I wish to pass through `by_group()`:

```
var_names <- c("var1", "var2")
```

And I attempt to pass the `var_names` vector through `do.call()`:

```
output <- do.call(by_group, as.list(c("df", var_names))
```

I get an error. How can I call my `by_group` function correctly?

Comment: list(df, varnames)? It's unclear what arguments your function expects.

Comment: `do.call(by_group, c(list(df),  as.list(var_names(ndf))))`

Comment: @headpoint this worked perfectly, many thanks.